# Random phantomjs timeout with Facebook web driver and Travis

Tags: php, facebook, phantomjs, travis-ci

Our Travis setup fails randomly due to timeout from phantomjs.

```
1) ls\tests\controllers\AdminViewsTest::testAdminSurveyViews with 
data set #7 ('surveyParticipantTokenOptions', array('survey/sa/rendersidemenulink/.../{SID}'))

Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown

for http POST to /session/25c1a410-c498-11e7-83b5-7dd62bd97597/url 
with params: {"url":"http:\/\/localhost\/index.php r=admin\/survey\/sa\/rendersidemenulink\/subaction\/tokens\/surveyid\/6485
34"}

Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

Is this a known issue?

**Edit**: In case someone else don't know this: phantomjs IS ABANDONED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phantomjs is abandoned. Use Firefox or Chromedriver instead.